# manupulation of Having in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I am checking duplicate records in a table using SelfJoin.

```
Table1:
column1 column2 column3
data1   data2    data3
data1   data2    data3
```

I have written below query which works fine in above case and give the required result.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1(nolock) A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT column1,
          column2,
          column3
   FROM table1(nolock)   
   GROUP BY column1,
            column2,
            column3
            HAVING count(1) > 1) B ON A.column1 = B.column1
AND A.column2 = B.column2
AND A.column3 = B.column3
```

But my another scenario is like where one column value contains as "ALL" which should be considered as same with other data.

```
Table1:
column1 column2 column3
data1   data2    ALL
data1   data2    data3
```

In above table column3 has one value as "ALL". In this case also I want to show duplicate records.
Please help me to modify above SQL to show duplicate records if one of the column value is "ALL".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT  t1.column1,
        t1.column2,
        t1.column3
FROM    table1 t1 join table2 t2 
        on  (t1.column1 = 'all' or t2.column1 = 'all' or t1.column1 = t2.column1) and
            (t1.column2 = 'all' or t2.column2 = 'all' or t1.column2 = t2.column2) and
            (t1.column3 = 'all' or t2.column3 = 'all' or t1.column3 = t2.column3)
group by t1.column1,
        t1.column2,
        t1.column3
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Paul..it has solved my second scenario but in first scenario I am getting only one record with above query.

Comment: I want all duplicate records when all columns are same.